# Query to get DAU and installs using self join

Tags: sql, analytics, presto

I have been struggling with getting number of DAU and number of installs per day broken down by a few user data such as platform, OS_version, country and a few other columns.
The idea is for the query to return something like:

`date       |DAU|Installs|Platform|OS_ver|country|
2017-05-01 | 2 | 0      |Android |5.0   | US    |
2017-05-01 | 1 | 1      |Android |6.0   | US    |
2017-05-01 | 1 | 1      |Android |6.0   | JP    |
2017-05-01 | 3 | 0      |Android |6.0   | MX    |
2017-05-01 | 10| 0      |Android |5.0   | MX    |`

As you can see, DAU and installs will be spread by those (and a few other) columns. Pretty straightforward analytics query.

All the information is located in the same table, so data need to be manipulated and joined by the table itself.

One column that will not be displaying info is the event column, which has the events for install and "screen" (the screen event is called every time a user open any screen in the game, even right after login, so "screen" events will be used to count the DAU).

My initial idea was to create two CTEs, each would have only records filtered by the events, one by install events, and the other by screen events, and then I'd extract the day part of the date (which in unix timestamp) and create another column in each CTE, install_day to count installs on the install CTE, and activity_day for the DAU CTE to calculate #DAU.

After creating those two CTEs I'd join them using the platform as condition like: dau_cte.platform = install_cte.platform.

I tried creating the query like that already in a few different ways but using the same logic described above, but got a bunch of duplicate data every time. So instead of showing my query code to help get it fixed I'd like to hear from the community what approach you guys would use to get these results.

BTW, this query will be running in Presto...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The query must be fairly simple. The final query should be grouped by `date`, `country`, `platform`, and `os_ver`. As far as I understand, two metrics of interest are distinct counts of some unique user (or event) identifier. According to presto docs there is no aggregation of type `COUNT_DISTINCT(X if Y)`, which leaves only to perform count distinct in sub-queries, as you mentioned. A query that follows will do just that. Note usage of `COALESCE` to account for missing data.

```
SELECT
        a.date,
        a.platform,
        a.os_ver,
        a.country,
        COALESCE(a.DAU, 0) as DAU,
        COALESCE(b.installs, 0) as installs,
FROM (
        SELECT
                date,
                platform,
                os_ver,
                country,
                COUNT(DISTINCT <user_id>) AS DAU
        FROM <table_name>
        WHERE event_name = 'screen'
        GROUP BY 1,2,3,4 
) a
FULL JOIN (
        SELECT
                date,
                platform,
                os_ver,
                country,
                COUNT(DISTINCT <user_id>) AS installs
        FROM <table_name>
        WHERE event_name = 'install'
        GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
) b
ON
        a.date = b.date
        AND a.platform = b.platform
        AND a.os_ver = b.os_ver
        AND a.country = b.country
```

Comment: Thank you Nikolay, I'm going to try later and post back the results.
Well remembered on the need for coalesce.
What about when I add more columns to this query, should the new columns be added both within the subqueries, to the group by clause, and after at the ON condition as well?

Comment: Yes, unless you are using some other unique identifier to group by or UDAF to do the count distinct.